# Search blob storage data

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sql-database

I have a large amount of diagnostics data stored in an Azure Blob Storage. Is there any way I can get that data searchable from my Azure SQL database? I would like to join on some custom data fields in my blob stored data.

Answer (score 1):

Blob storage doesn't have searchable metadata, per se: You may certainly search containers for given blob names, and you may even enumerate blobs to look at their metadata. But aside from the container/blob URI, there's no built-in search mechanisms.

If you want to search for metadata, you'll need to build your own data store (e.g.e in a searchable database such as SQL Database, the one you mentioned). This would be completely up to your app to do (you'd need to extract specific data you want to search, and store it in your database engine of choice). You'd then need to link your database engine's contents back to blob storage (e.g. store a blob's url alongside its metadata).

If you're talking about full-text search, you'd need to employ an appropriate fts tool. Azure provides Azure Search as a 1st-party full-text-search service, or you may certainly use a 3rd-party tool or service. What you choose is completely up to you.

Comment: My data is fairly ordered, most of it is csv data that I have the schema for. I just wanted to avoid having to build some additional tool to extract it and then load it into some additional datastore.

Comment: Azure Search is definitely the tool for the job then